# rad grid Image Colume with webapi data source

Tags: asp.net, telerik, asp.net-web-api, radgrid

I am using a RadGrid with web API data source. The problem is when I add an image column the image is still empty.

This is my grid:

```
<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="grdUsers" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true"
AllowFilteringByColumn="true" PageSize="5">
    <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" ClientDataKeyNames="Id,PasswordHash">
        <PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages" AlwaysVisible="true" />
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridImageColumn DataType="System.String" DataImageUrlFields="Image" AlternateText="User image" UniqueName="Image"
                ImageAlign="Middle" ImageHeight="50px" ImageWidth="50px" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderText="">
            </telerik:GridImageColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn  DataField="UserName" HeaderText="User Name"   UniqueName="UserName"
                DataType="System.String">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn  DataField="FullName" HeaderText="Name" UniqueName="FullName"  
                DataType="System.String">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn  DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email"  UniqueName="Email"
                DataType="System.String">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="RegistrationDate" HeaderText="Registration Date" UniqueName="RegistrationDate"  
                DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridButtonColumn UniqueName="btnEdit"  ButtonType="PushButton" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit"></telerik:GridButtonColumn>
            <telerik:GridButtonColumn UniqueName="btnDelete" ButtonCssClass="del" ButtonType="PushButton" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete"></telerik:GridButtonColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
    <ClientSettings>
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
        <ClientEvents OnCommand="RadGridCommand" />
        <DataBinding Location="/SecuHostapi/Security/User/GetAll"  ResponseType="JSON">
            <DataService TableName="SecuHostUser" Type="OData" />
        </DataBinding>
    </ClientSettings>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

and the result
[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

after deep search the problem was i have to add this  DataImageUrlFormatString="/{0}" 
for GridImageColumn